# How set swift 3 UITextField border color?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield

Hello i have working no error codes for UITextfield border color change but when using it in Swift 3 dont change textfield border color and dont gives error. I need your help my codes under below.

```
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pass: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myColor : UIColor = UIColor.white()
    email.layer.borderColor = myColor.cgColor
    pass.layer.borderColor = myColor.cgColor


}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You also need to set `border width`, because your border color is set already but your default border width is 0.0 so you can't see it.

So, set border width something like,

```
  email.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

**Update :**

Your code should be like,

```
 @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var pass: UITextField!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   let myColor = UIColor.white
   email.layer.borderColor = myColor.cgColor
   pass.layer.borderColor = myColor.cgColor

   email.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
   pass.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

}
```

Comment: thank you worked i think will be help many people can u write full codes into your answer i will accept it

Comment: You're welcome...:) updated answer as per your suggestion.. :)

Comment: i think you need to remove () in swift 3

Comment: borderColor doesnt work unless you also set the borderWidth

Comment: Also you can add this: `email.layer.cornerRadius = 4`

Answer (score 12):

Use the below code in `swift 3`:

in view did load

```
 outer_line.layer.borderWidth = 1
 outer_line.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
```

Answer (score 10):

Try to use this,
It might be helpful to you

```
let myColor : UIColor = UIColor( red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue:0, alpha: 1.0 )
myTextField.layer.masksToBounds = true
myTextField.layer.borderColor = myColor.CGColor
myTextField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

Answer (score 10):

I think you should first provide a `borderWidth`

```
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pass: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let myColor : UIColor = UIColor.white()
email.layer.borderWidth = 1
email.layer.borderColor = myColor.cgColor
pass.layer.borderColor = myColor.cgColor


}
```

and then set a color :)

Answer (score 6):

> Updated Swift 3 :

**if you want to set the bottom border to UITextField, used below lines of code :**

// function defination :

```
func setBottomBorderToTextFields()  {

    let bottomLine = CALayer()
    bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yourTextFieldName.frame.height - 1, width: yourTextFieldName.frame.width, height: 1)
    bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor // background color
    yourTextFieldName.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.none // border style
    yourTextFieldName.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
}
```

// In ViewDidLoad() :

```
self.setBottomBorderToTextFields()
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the `borderWidth` from the `UITextField`'s `layer` property.

Like: `email.layer.borderWidth = 1`.

Also, if you frequently need to set borders to your views, you can make an extension like this:

```swift
extension UIView {
    func addBorderAndColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat, corner_radius: CGFloat = 0, clipsToBounds: Bool = false) {
        self.layer.borderWidth = width
        self.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = corner_radius
        self.clipsToBounds = clipsToBounds
    }
}
```

Call this like:
`email.addBorderAndColor(color: UIColor.white, width: 0.5, corner_radius: 5, clipsToBounds: true)`

Since this method sets the `borderWidth`, it will also solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is working.

1. give border width
2. and after give bgcolor.

```
txtemail.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
txtemail.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
```

It definitely works

Comment: Isnt it same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48335817/4826457)